# How to encrypt or hide user id on url bar? rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

for now when i click user with id = 1, on url bar its

> users/1

I want to change it to

> users/[encrypt]

or

> users/some_user

is there any way to do that on rails?

Comment: Do you want a user to be able to view other users?

Answer (score 3):

What about using a permalink instead of the users id? i.e. users/[permalink] and you can configure the permalink to anything you like as long as it is a unique value

Checkout the friendly_id gem: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Comment: Using a randomly (or pseudo-randomly) generated unique id (which friendly_id lets you do easily) is the way to go i think, if you don't want people to be able to guess user ids (which is what i assume you meant by the [encrypt] thing.  All of your database associations will still use id, it's just the urls that will use the random-looking slug.

Comment: yeah, i want to hide user_id

Answer (score 0):

Rails uses `to_param` method when displaying object in url.

If you change `to_param` method in `user` it will, be used to display data instead of `id`.

By default rails has implemented `to_param` to return `id` of the object.

For example

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def to_param
    "#{self.first_name}-#{self.last_name}" # or whatever you want to use
  end
  ...
end
```

In your url you will have `/users/first_name-last_name` or whatever your `to_param` method returns. By default `to_param` returns `id` and in `url` you get `/users/4`. and in your controller you can find `user` with `id` 4, but when you change `to_param` method, you have to change respectively the way you fetch user from database.

Example:
 I change my `to_param` method to return `nick_name` from database, and it is unique for the particular user, that I can use to find user from database.
In router

change the mappings for `params`

```
get 'users/:nick_name', 'users#show'
```

In controller

```
User.find_by :nick_name => params[:nick_name]
```

Comment: well, when i add this method on my user model, i get a error "Couldn't find User with 'id'=some-user", anyway to fix that?

Comment: You need unique value to be returned with `to_param` method, because you will use that to find user in database. Right now your route is `/users/some-user' but how who can determine which user it is, you need some unique param in url that will be linked to particular user

Comment: i am quite confused now Q.Q

Answer (score 0):

like others in this post says , i use
i use 
https://github.com/norman/friendly_id this way:

```
  # app/models/secret.rb; this would go in the model you want to obfuscate
  class Secret < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_friendly_id :code, :use_slug => true

    validates :name, :uniqueness => true

    def code
       Digest::SHA1.hexdigest self.name
    end
  end
```

it’s simple. If your security needs are serious you’d probably want something a little more complex (not to mention more layered than a basic obfuscation technique), but I wanted to share an out-of-the-box way to use a gem that already exists (and may even be in use in your app already)